# Python-Dictionary parsing and update better

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an input dictionary which looks like this:

```
{"payment": 
    {"payment_id": "AAHPW34190", "clm_list": 
        {"dtl": 
            [{"clm_id": "1A2345"},
             {"clm_id": "9999"}
            ]},
         "payment_amt": "20"}}
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
{ "create":  
    { "_index": "website", "_type": "blog", "_id": "AAHPW34190"}}
{"payment_id": "AAHPW34190", "clm_list": 
    {"dtl": 
        [{"clm_id": "1A2345"},
         {"clm_id": "9999"}
        ]},
     "payment_amt": "20"}
```

The value of _id in the first line of output is derived from payment_id.
I can get the above output easily, by doing the following:

```
static_line={ "create":  { "_index": "website", "_type": "blog", "_id": "0"}}
orig={"payment": {"payment_id": "AAHPW34190", "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345"}, {"clm_id": "9999"}]}, "payment_amt": "20"}}`
sec_line=orig["payment"]
static_line["_id"]=sec_line["payment_id"]`
```

But my input is going to be a million dict elements, and I want to do it as efficiently as possible.
So can I do it better for a million dicts?

Comment: are you reading this data from a file or is it already in memory?

Comment: In prod I will be reading it from a file, and the output will be in a file. I'm planning to use GNU parallel to spit the input file and feed it to all the cores of the server, thereby parallelizing the process

Answer (score 0):

I reformat the output of your input dict. suppose that the following dict is an element of a list, in which there are millions of dict.

```
{"payment": {"payment_id": "AAHPW34190",
               "clm_list": {"dtl": [{"clm_id": "1A2345"}, {"clm_id":"9999"}]},
            "payment_amt": "20"}
}
```

use a list comprehension to extract the payment_id and create new dict

```
[{ "create":  { "_index": "website", "_type": "blog", "_id": d['payment']['payment_id']}} 
for d in my_list_of_dict]
```